# php help update multiple rows in html fetched from the database

Tags: php

could someone help me on how to update the following table with the buttons on the side ore cancel for different rows fetched from the database?
below is my code

I have two problems, I can select all but I cant update them in the database `(updating to approved)` and the other thing I want if a cancel button is clicked, to update the reg Status to canceled. thanks in advance for your help

```
<form method="post" name="myform" action="checkboxes.asp">
    <table class="table table-bordered" id="dataTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>No</th>
                <th>Reg Number</th>
                <th>Reg Date</th>
                <th>Reg Time</th>
                <th>Reg Status</th>
                <th><a href="javascript:;" id="Check_All" onClick="Check(document.myform.check_list); return false">
                        Approve All</a></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>No</th>
                <th>Reg Number</th>
                <th>Reg Date</th>
                <th>Reg Time</th>
                <th>Reg Status</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
        <tbody>
            <?php
            include('server.php');

            $servername = "localhost";
            $username = "root";
            $password = "";
            $dbname = "registration";
            $status = "";

            try {
                $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
            } catch (Msqli_sql_Exception $ex) {
                echo("error in conection");
            }
            $query = "SELECT * FROM registrationstatus";
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
            if (!$result) {
                die('SQL Error: ' . mysqli_error($conn));
            }
            $no = 1;
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                echo '<tr>
                      <td>' . $no . '</td>
                      <td>' . $row['regno'] . '</td>
                      <td>' . $row['date'] . '</td>
                      <td>' . $row['time'] . '</td>
                      <td>' . $row['status'] . '</td>
                      <td><button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" class="nav-link" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#cancelReg"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                      <input type="checkbox" name="check_list" value="1">Approve<br>
                      </td>
                      </tr>';
                $no++;
            }
            ?>
        <script language="JavaScript">
            function Check(chk) {
                var checkedVal = document.getElementById("Check_All");
                if (checkedVal.innerHTML == "Approve All") {
                    for (i = 0; i < chk.length; i++)
                        chk[i].checked = true;
                    checkedVal.innerHTML = "UnApprove All";
                } else {
                    for (i = 0; i < chk.length; i++)
                        chk[i].checked = false;
                    checkedVal.innerHTML = "Approve All";
                }
            }
        </script>              
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
</div>
<div class="card-footer small text-muted"> <button type="submit" name="confirm" style="margin-left:80%;">
        approve</button></div>
</form>
```